# How to control values and text in spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I want to build android app with spinner , I would like to appear in spinner some text , and when selected, it appears in TextView other text than the value of which is a selected.
for example , i want to appear in spinner website name (like= stackoverflow) and when select appear in TextView the website URL (like=https://stackoverflow.com/)

can anyone help me?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add text to spinner like this:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

List<String> texts = new ArrayList<String>();
texts.add("Google");
texts.add("Facebook");

List<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();
urls.add("www.google.com");
urls.add("www.facebook.com");

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, texts);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

then you need to listen for item selected on spinner

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        String url = urls.get(i);
        // do with url whatever you need
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        // do nothing
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you create yourself an Object:

```
public class LanguageObject {
    private String title;
    private String url;

    public LanguageObject(String title, String url) {
        this.title = title;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public Integer getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
```

}

Then, in your Activity/Fragment, you create an ArrayList with the objects you need:

```
ArrayList<SpinnerObject> spinnerObjectList = new ArrayList<SpinnerObject>();
        spinnerObjectList.add(new SpinnerObject("Google", "www.google.com"));
        spinnerObjectList.add(new SpinnerObject("StackOverflow", "www.stackoverflow.com"));
```

In addition to that, create a custom adapter that will handle your data:

```
public class SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SpinnerObject> {
public SpinnerAdapter (Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<SpinnerObject> spinnerObjects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, spinnerObjects);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    SpinnerObject spinnerObject = getItem(position);

    if(view == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

        view = layoutInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, null);

        if (view != null) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            textView.setText(spinnerObject.getTitle());
        }
    }

    return view;
}
```

Now you can use this adapter on your Spinner, and get the url when one of the items was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

For adding text in spinner you can use following code in `onCreate()`

```
Spinner locale;
ArrayList<String> lList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


     locale =(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Cmblocale);

    // bind data to Spinner(ComboBox)
    lList =new ArrayList<String>();
    lList.add("English");
    lList.add("Canada");
    lList.add("Chinese");
    lList.add("French");
    lList.add("Germany");
    lList.add("Japan");
    ArrayAdapter<String> cAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,lList);

    locale.setAdapter(cAdapter);
}
```

For Retrieving value use following code inside your `setOnItemSelectedListener` on spinner

```
if(locale.getSelectedItem().equals("English"))
    {
        txtText.setText(English);
    }else if(locale.getSelectedItem().equals("Chinese"))
    {
        txtText.setText(Chinese);
    }else if(locale.getSelectedItem().equals("Canada"))
    {
        txtText.setText(Canada);
    }else if(locale.getSelectedItem().equals("French"))
    {
        txtText.setText(French);
    }else if(locale.getSelectedItem().equals("Germany"))
    {
        txtText.setText(Germany);
    }else if(locale.getSelectedItem().equals("Japan"))
    {
        txtText.setText(Japan);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner); //create a spinner view in XML

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
    R.array.your_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item); // create adapter which has second parameter as the array which contains the values you want to show as entries of spinner
spinner.setAdapter(adapter); // set the adapter to your spinner and your spinner will show the values from array that you set in second parameter of adapter
```

**To listen to the click on the options of the spinner**

```
public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
...

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
        int pos, long id) {
    // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
    // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // Another interface callback
}
}
```

Now to show the appropriate link of the website for selected option from spinner you can have a map which has keys as  same as the spinner values and values as websites as you want....

```
HashMap<String, String> nameWebsiteMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
nameWebsite.put("stack overflow","http://stackoverflow.com/"); // for example
```

So in `onItemSelected` you can simply do this

```
selectedSiteName = nameWebsite.get(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());
textView.setText(selectedSiteName);
```

Comment: dont use comment for thank you and +1 votes if the answer helped you just make a upvote or mark it as accepted answer that will be of great help for future readers too....